# Ubuntu installed on MAC has ethernet and WIFI problem

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, network-manager, mac

I have problems with my Internet connection and interfaces. I will give those info below to help and explain my problems.

1- Ethernet (cable): 
Internet works through cable but only if I boot Ubuntu with the cable plugged in. When I unplug it and replug it then it can't be connected (means no Internet till I reboot again with the wire plugged in).  Any idea?

2- Wireless:
I tried many solutions over Internet but still can't see the interface and the wifi doesn't work. please let me show what I have done so far:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

Results:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0112]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

I used this solution:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

I also tried this command:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

My hands are really tied now and wonder if some of you has a solution for both or at least second problem.

Thank you very much all.

Answer (score 1):

The command that should make wifi work is `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and edit question to include results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and I will see what I can find

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy, you are a life saver. Actually that package just solved the problem immediately. By the way, I also edited the question as you asked.

Comment: For some reason the command didn't show your ethernet so lets try `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 200`

Comment: The final step for me was `modprobe wl`, which wasn't being loaded for some reason.